# How might I send an 87kb transaction to Solana?

Tags: transactions, transaction

This is part of a Lamport password scheme (no relation to the lamport currency unit), that worked on EVM but is too big for Solana. How can I easily send this kind of transaction to a Solana program?

It's theoretically quantum-hard, so that's what the fuss is for.

I want to put password controls on a minting program so the quantum boogeyman doesn't ruin my dapp.